# ECharts - Looking for the ability to make the last point of a line graph blink

Tags: echarts

I have a line graph that receives and displays real-time data. I would like to have the last point of the line be a circle that blinks slowly to reinforce the idea that the graph is real-time. Note that the showSymbol attribute of the series is false.

Is there any way to do this on echarts?

Answer (score 1):

To display a point on the last point of your data, you can use a `markPoint`.
But it doesn't have an option to make it blink so you can instead use a trick like changing its `itemStyle.opacity` periodically.

Here is an example : (you can copy the following code at the end of this [echart example](https://echarts.apache.org/examples/en/editor.html?c=dynamic-data2) to try it out)

```
var v = 0
setInterval(function () {
  v = v + 0.01
  if(v >= 1) {
    v = 0.2
  }
  myChart.setOption({
    series: [
      {
        markPoint: {
          animation: false,
          symbol: 'circle',
          data: [
            { 
              xAxis: data[data.length-1].value[0], 
              yAxis: data[data.length-1].value[1],
              symbolSize: 10,
              itemStyle: {
                opacity: v
              },
            }
          ]
        },
      }
    ]
  });
}, 20);
```

There you have a blinking point on the last point of a real-time graphe. You can easily change the way the `markPoint` looks (shape, color, position ...) : see [markPoint doc](https://echarts.apache.org/en/option.html#series-line.markPoint).